# Deal with no internet connection in windows 8 app using bing map api

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, bing-maps, internet-connection

I am creating a Windows 8.1 app using Bing map sdk in C# using this guide  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408457/Using-Bing-Maps-For-Windows-8-Metro-Apps-Csharp-Ja.

Now when I am using this app without internet connection the app crashes. So how can I deal with this no internet connection exception?

Comment: "So how can I deal with this no internet connection exception?" - the same way that you deal with any other problem where it's not anything under your program's control to prevent - you have to catch exceptions when they occur, and then decide whether to re-attempt what you just tried or to just give up and tell the user that. Both the current answers are equally wrong-headed because they believe that it's possible to "pre-check" for something that can change its actual state at any time and not under *your* program's control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this property in `App.xaml.cs` as use it to test if Internet is available or not

```
public static bool IsInternetAvailable
{
    get
    {
        var profiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
        var internetProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
        return profiles.Any(s => s.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            || (internetProfile != null
                    && internetProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
    }
}

if(App.IsInternetAvailable)
{
    //Do operation of Bing map
}
else
{
    //Show message dialog
}
```

Comment: See my comment to interneo's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21184556/15498) - the same question can be asked of this property.

Answer (score 0):

Check it first?

For example by method:

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.bing.com"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code is for windows phone. But my app is for windows 8.1 app

Comment: And immediately after this function returns, but before your code has done anything with the result, the external reality changes. So you have to write code that, even after this function has returned true, has to deal with the internet not being available (or changing part way through using it). Given that you have to write this code *anyway* to produce robust software, what possible benefit is there in calling this function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for windows 8.1

```
public static bool have_net()
    {
        ConnectionProfile InternetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        if (InternetConnectionProfile == null) return false;

        NetworkConnectivityLevel ncl = InternetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel();

        if (ncl == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
        {
            return true;
        }

        bool b1 = InternetConnectionProfile.IsWwanConnectionProfile;
        bool b2 = InternetConnectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile;

        return (b1 || b2);
    }
```